# Roll-forward to next valid datetime in chrono-tz

Tags: rust, rust-chrono

If I have

```
// Cargo.toml
[package]
name = "tmp"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[dependencies]
chrono = "0.4.31"
chrono-tz = "0.8.3"
```

```
// src/main.rs
use chrono::{NaiveDate, NaiveDateTime, TimeZone};
use chrono_tz::Europe::London;

fn main() {
    let dt = NaiveDateTime::parse_from_str("2020-03-29T01:00:00", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S").unwrap();
    let dt = London.from_local_datetime(&dt);
    println!("res: {:?}", dt);
}
```

and run `cargo run`, I get

```
res: None
```

Indeed, 2020-03-29T01:00:00 in Europe/London is a non-existent datetime due to daylight savings.

So, how can I get it to "roll forwards" to the next valid datetime in this time zone?

I can't just try adding an extra hour, unfortunately, as not all time zones go forwards by 1 hour during DST (e.g. Lord Howe goes forwards by half-an-hour). Furthermore, there may be non-existent datetimes due to calendar changes, where I'd need to go forwards more than half-an-hour.

Would just going forwards in half-hour-increments until I find a datetime that parses be a good solution?

Comment: This is a really annoying and unexpected problem! I could imagine this causing random bugs all over the place around certain dates.

Comment: A possible solution could be: convert the origin date time to MS and build the target date from the MS: `let dt = London.timestamp_millis_opt(dt.timestamp_millis());`. it resulted for me: `2020-03-29T02:00:00BST`